# Segfault in libc-2.19.so with Webmin

Tags: linux-kernel, webmin, virtualmin, libc6

I recently upgraded the kernel one of my Debian 8 servers which has Webmin+Virtualmin installed on it. The server had usual Virtualmin backups setup which used to work fine before the upgrade, but post the upgrade the backups stopped working with no error on Webmin/Virtualmin logs. While trying to perform manual backups (which again failed without any error) I checked `dmesg` on the server and found the following error showing up repeatedly:

```
    [78773.181504] /usr/share/webm[18688]: segfault at f8e0070 ip 00007f45bcc895df sp 00007ffc2085dab0 error 6 in libc-2.19.so[7f45bcc0f000+1a2000]
    [79188.007475] monitor.pl[19085]: segfault at 4ead470 ip 00007ff2935805df sp 00007ffc5c2d5aa0 error 6 in libc-2.19.so[7ff293506000+1a2000]
```

And this error popped up after every time I tried running the backup.

Can any one suggest how can I fix this issue?

Also, my current kernel string output from `uname -a` is

```
    Linux srv1 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2 (2016-04-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Finally solved it. It seems to be an issue with MySQL Perl DBI for MySQL 5.7 (https://sourceforge.net/p/webadmin/bugs/4476/). Solved it by setting `nodbi=1` in /etc/webmin/mysql/config